# PHPhotoLibraryPreventAutomaticLimitedAccessAlert still shows select photos option while presenting photo library

Tags: ios, swift

As per the quick read the purpose of this key
"**PHPhotoLibraryPreventAutomaticLimitedAccessAlert**" is to prevent limited library access. I have added this option in info.plist but it still shows "Select photos" option in permissions dialogue.

[image]

The code of getting permissions is following.

```
func checkPhotoLibraryPermission(completionBlock completion: @escaping ()->Void) {
        let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            completion()
            break
        case .notDetermined,.denied,.restricted:
            // ask for permissions
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
                switch status {
                case .authorized:
                    completion()
                    break
                case .notDetermined,.denied,.restricted:
                    self.alertToEncouragePhotoLibraryAccessWhenApplicationStarts()
                    break
                case .limited:
                    break
                }
            }
            break
        case .limited:
            break
        }
    }
```

Anyone please mention what is the exact purpose of this key and is it possible to even force drop this option ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As far as i know the purpose of this key "PHPhotoLibraryPreventAutomaticLimitedAccessAlert" is to prevent limited library access.

That's incorrect. You *cannot* prevent use of limited authorization. It is built into the system and the user can always specify it.

So what is this key for? Well, if the user *does* specify limited access, the system may put up the Select Photos interface again from time to time to see whether the user wants to *change* what photos your app can access. PHPhotoLibraryPreventAutomaticLimitedAccessAlert prevents *that*. It does *not* prevent the user from specifying limited access in the initial authorization request alert or the Settings app.

Comment: Got it. Thanks alot.

Comment: Answer was very to the point. I will further look into your articles. Thanks

Comment: If you could share the link of your book. It will be appreciated.

Comment: This is correct. I have found that the native photos picker still appears if the user changes permissions settings in the Settings app. But hopefully, this preference will prevent photos pickers from appearing in our apps. This preference makes sense if you have a custom button to change the selection.